# How do I enable DEBUG for glassfish domain server.log via linux command line?

Tags: glassfish

There are lots of `INFO` in `logging.properties` file. Which one should I change to DEBUG/FINE for getting detailed logs?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140168/manually-changing-glassfish-domain-xml-for-debug-error
I've read these answers and they don't answer the question.

`com.sun.enterprise.server.level=FINE`

Can I just add these lines?